# Backbone - Possible to get the collection from a model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm wondering if there's a way to get a reference to a collection from one of its models.  For instance, if any of the people in the collection below are somehow aware of belonging to a collection, or multiple collections.  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jelatin/aZcJV/11/)

```
(function() {
window.App = {
    Models: {},
    Views: {},
    Collections: {}
};

App.Models.Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: 'John',
        phone: '555-555-5555'
    }
});

App.Views.Person = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',

    template: _.template("<%= name %> -- <%= phone %>"),

    render: function(){
        var template = this.template( this.model.toJSON() );

        this.$el.html( template );

        return this;
    }
});

App.Collections.People = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Models.Person 
});

App.Views.People = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',

    add: function(person){
        var personView = new App.Views.Person({ model: person });

        this.$el.append( personView.render().el );

        return this;
    },

    render: function() {
        this.collection.each(this.add, this);

        return this;
    }
});


})();

var peeps = [ { name: 'Mary' }, { name: 'David' }, { name: 'Tiffany' } ];

var people = new App.Collections.People(peeps);

var peopleView = new App.Views.People({ collection: people });

peopleView.render().$el.appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Each model has a property called `collection`. In your fiddle, adding `console.log(people.models[0].collection)` will print out the collection.

Looking through the source code, it looks like this is what's used to do things like remove a model from a collection when the model's `destroy()` method is called.

Update: see [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctasims/vfSxQ/2/) which creates three person models and two collections. It prints them to the console. It looks like `model.collection` only refers to the first collection the person was added to, not the second.